# Any example of non-closed operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I cannot think of one.

By the way, is there any good exercise book on functional analysis or hilbert space?

Comment: there is a problem book by Paul Halmos which I felt was good http://www.amazon.in/Hilbert-Space-Problem-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387906851

Comment: Any operator whose domain is not closed, for starters.

Comment: I see. You simply exclude the limit out of the domain.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Unbounded selfadjoint operators on dense domains are closed, even though their domains are not.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Hmm, is there an error in [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators), then? It seems to imply directly that the domain of a closed operator must be closed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Closed for an operator just means that the graph is closed in the product topology. So, for example, if $A$ is bounded, injective, but has dense range that is not closed, then $A^{-1}$ is closed on its domain, which is the range of $A$. It's closed because the graph of $A^{-1}$ is just the transpose of the graph of $A$. Equivalently, $x_{n}\in\mathcal{D}(A)\rightarrow x$ and $Ax_{n} \rightarrow y$ implies $x \in\mathcal{D}(A)$ with $Ax=y$. That's the meaning of having a closed graph. But that does not imply a closed domain.

Answer (score 4):

Any bounded operator $A$ on a dense vector subspace $D$ of a Hilbert space $H$ such that $D\neq H.$

Answer (score 2):

For a concrete example of an operator that isn't even closable, consider
$$ M: (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)\mapsto(x_1,2x_2,3x_2,\ldots,nx_n,\ldots)$$
defined on the subspace of sequences with bounded support in $\ell^2$.

Then the sequence $(\frac 1n \mathbf e_n)_n$ clearly converges (to 0), but $(M(\frac 1n\mathbf e_n))_n = (\mathbf e_n)_n$ doesn't.

Comment: This operator seems to be self-adjoint and thus is also closed. What goes wrong in the example is that for closedness from $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ and $M\phi_n \rightarrow \psi$ it must follow $\phi \in D(M)$ and $M\phi=\psi$, but in the example above the second sequence does not even converge.

Comment: An example that solves this problem is operator M defined on sequences of bounded support that sends $\mathbf{e_n}$ to $n\mathbf{e_1}$.  Then $\frac{1}{n}{\mathbf{e_n}} \rightarrow 0$ and $M(\frac{1}{n}{\mathbf{e_n}}) \rightarrow \mathbf{e_1}$.